# C# async/await - multiple tasks with one preferred

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have the following scenario/requirement:

I have two tasks, task A and task B, which both return the same type of data.
If task A, upon completion, has data in its result, I need to return the result of Task A - otherwise I return the result of task B.

I'm trying to performance optimize this for parallellism and I'm unsure if there's a better way than what I'm doing.  This seems like a lot of code to do what I want.

```
var firstSuccessfulTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskA, taskB);
if (firstSuccessfulTask != taskA)
{
    await taskA;
}

if (taskA.Result != null)
{
    return taskA.Result;
}

return await taskB;
```

Comment: Why not just call `await taskA` first and skip the `Task.WhenAny` call?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just write the code just the way your requirements read.  return the result of A, unless it's null, in which case, return the result of B.

```
return await taskA ?? await taskB;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that not start the execution of taskB until taskA has completed, effectively making them serial and not parallel?

Comment: @PaulGelardi If `taskB` is actually a property that starts the task when you call that expression, then yes.  If it's a local/field that has an already started task, then no.  Given the naming convention, and the fact that you use `taskA` repeatedly (and thus clearly aren't creating new tasks each time you use it, because if you were the code wouldn't work at all) it makes it pretty clear that they're both variables, not expressions that compute new tasks.  In the event that they really are expressions that compute new tasks, you'll need to store it in a local variable first, then do this.

Comment: That makes sense.  I wasn't aware the taskB started executing as soon as I called the async method - I thought it didn't start until something was waiting for,
 or awaiting it.

Comment: @PaulGelardi `await` just "waits" for it to finish, its not called `astart` after all ;). But seriously, if you try to await a Task that represents a thread that has not been started (via calling `new Task(...)` instead of using the more correct `Task.Run(...)`) the await will never return until the thread is started somewhere else and then completes.

Comment: @PaulGelardi: Remember, `await` does not *create* asynchrony. It *describes a restriction on a control flow involving existing asynchronous tasks*. The restriction is *the code which follows an await does not execute until after the task has completed*.

Comment: @EricLippert That's a really good way to word it. I haven't really had to peel back the layers of async/await and look under the syntactic sugar covers yet.   Would it suffice to say that the compiler is taking whatever code exists after the await and putting it in a .ContinueWith?

Comment: @PaulGelardi It's doing something semantically equivalent, so that's exactly how you should think of it, but the actual implementation details technically use a different means of accomplishing that same thing, and there are also a few things that it does in addition to that with respect to error handling and using the synchronization context that it's important to understand.